# Multiplicative group of an infinite field is not cyclic

Tags: field-theory, cyclic-groups

**Question.**

> Prove  that  the  multiplicative  group  of any  infinite  field  can  never  be  cyclic .

$\mathbb R$, $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb C$ are some infinite fields whose multiplicative groups are not cyclic, I know.

I  need  some  lead  as  to  how  to  begin  the  proof.

Sorry  for  the  lack  of   work  on  my  part (I'm  clueless)  and  any  help  is  appreciated.

Comment: HINT: What is the multiplicative order of $-1$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott :  $2$ . Then $?$

Comment: Does an infinite cyclic group have any element of order $2$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : No . So  that  is  the  contradiction  $?$

Comment: Yes, you can phrase it as a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  :  The  book  this  problem  is  from  says  to  consider fields  of  _char_ 0  and  _char_  $p$   separately .  But  this  logic  does  not  use  characteristic  of  fields  anywhere . So  is  a  different  approach  needed  now  $?$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : You are assuming that the characteristic is not 2.

Comment: @Nate  :  What  goes  wrong  when  characteristic  is  $2$  $?$

Comment: @user80631: Yes; on account of your examples I was thinking of fields of characteristic $0$. The same argument works provided that the characteristic is not $2$, as Nate mentions. That leaves only characteristic $2$ to be dealt with separately.

Comment: -1 =1 in characteristic 2

Comment: @BrianM.Scott :  Pls , help  me  with  that  $p\neq 2$ case then .

Comment: @Nate  :  Ok .  Then  do  you  think  for  _char_ 0  and  _char_ $p\neq 2$  the  same  logic  that  Brian Scott  gave  will  work  $?$

Comment: I think BrianM.Scott gave more or less the whole idea of the proof in those cases.  An infinite cyclic group has no nontrivial elements of finite order, but -1 always has order 2 so the multiplicative group cannot be cyclic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok here is the characteristic 2 case:

Assume $k$ is an infinite field of characteristic $2$ with a cyclic multiplicative group.  Note that any element of an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ has finite multiplicative order, so this implies that every element of $k-\{0,1\}$ must be transcendental.

Next let $x$ be a generator for the multiplicative group, which exists as we are assuming it is cyclic.  Consider the element $1+x$ of our field. It is nonzero and therefore equal to some power of $x$ since $x$ is a generator.  But then $1+x=x^n$ for some $n$, so $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_2$, contradicting the above claim.

Comment: Given the hint in the book it might be worth adding that this proof works for any positive characteristic $p$ (replacing $k - \{0,1\}$ by $k- F_p$)

Comment: @Nate :  One  step  is  not  clear  to  me . "_Any_  _element_  _of_  _algebraic_  _extension_  _of_  _of_  $\mathbb F_2$ _has_  _finite_  _multiplicative_  _order_"  . Could  you  please  give  a  little  more  explanation   of  that  $?$  . Thank  you .

Comment: @user118494 the field generated by an algebraic element will be an extension of $F_2$ of finite degree. Thus,  a finite field, in which the order thus ought to be finite. (That there is a larger surrounding field is not relevant.)

Answer (score 8):

I was studying this for a Galois Theory course and also bumped into this question, and actually for fields of characteristic different from 2 there is a really surprisingly simple proof (spoiler, this will happen because in characteristic $2$ we get $-1=1$).
So suppose $k$ is an infinite field such that char $k \neq 2$ and there is $x$ with $\langle x \rangle = k^*$. This implies that there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (different than $0$ because $-1 \neq 1$) such that $x^n = -1$, which implies that $x^{2n} = 1$ and so $k^*$ is finite, contradiction.