# Can you check my proof that $\mathbb Q^* = \mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ under multiplication is not cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, cyclic-groups

I want to prove that $\mathbb Q^* = \mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ under multiplication is not cyclic, and I've seen this proof [Nonzero rationals under multiplication are not a cyclic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673439/nonzero-rationals-under-multiplication-are-not-a-cyclic-group), but I wanted to check if the proof I made up for this problem was also a valid proof (or if not, why). My proof is as follows: Suppose to the contrary that $\exists$ an element $(a/b) \in Q^*$ such that $<a/b> = Q^*$, where a, b $\neq$ 0, and a and b are relatively prime integers. Then, $\forall q \in Q^*$, $\exists$ $n \in Z$ such that $(a/b)^{n}$ = $a^{n}/b^{n}$ = q. Suppose q is an integer. Then $q^{n}b^{n} = a^{n}$, and thus $b^{n}|a^{n}$, so $b|a$. This is a contradiction with a and b being relatively prime, and thus $Q^*$ is not cyclic.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Note that $b\mid a$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is actually possible, if $b=\pm1$; but this is a case you can quickly address.

Comment: Up to the detail mentionned by Greg Martin, your proof is essentially the same as the one in your link [Nonzero rationals under multiplication are not a cyclic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673439/nonzero-rationals-under-multiplication-are-not-a-cyclic-group) and that proof was already aproved

Comment: Actually we can make the more general statement that for any infinite field $K$, the multiplicative group $K^*$ is not cyclic.   Check the two answers over [here][1].


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1448281/1070376